# Redirect from Facebook's iPhone App to Safari

Tags: iphone, facebook, cookies

When clicking external links in **Facebook's iPhone App** you are staying within the App itself instead of going to **Safari**. I want people coming to my site to open my site in Safari (or whatever browser) instead. Is there anything I can do about that?

The problem is that my **Cookie-based Authentication** using ASP.NET is not working, for some reason, within Facebook's browser. This is only a problem when clicking my site link from within Facebook's Native iPhone App, it works fine from Facebooks webb app or opening directly from Safari.

Comment: The Authentication within Facebook Browser is actually working now. I don't know what fixed that. I still don't know how to transfer out of the Facebook browser though..